# Django:how to access to ForeignKey's model?

Tags: python, django

I need to access to `ForeignKey`'s model of a given model.

Here's the sample code:

```py
class modelA(models.db):
    field1 = models.ForeignKey('modelB')
class modelB(models.db):
    pass
## below is the pseudo code
modelA.get_model_of_fk('field1').objects.all() # fetch all objects of modelB
```

Of course it will be so easy if there's an instance of `modelA` involved. But I just can't find a way to do it without creating an instance of `modelA`.

My current solution:

```py
instance_of_a = modelA.objects.all()[0]
model_b = instance_of_a.field1.__class__
model_b.objects.all() # fetch all objects of modelB
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django's ContentType framework is built for this. You can refer the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#methods-on-contenttype-instances).

In your case,

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
model_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(modelA.field1)
model_type.model_class().objects.all() # this will get you all objects of the foreign key model
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized that, django itself must know what model a `ForeignKey` field links to, so I dug into django's source code and find this seems works:

```
modelA.field1.field.rel.to.objects.all() # same as modelB.objects.all()
```

Comment: Django has a framework for implementing this. See my answer below. What you've implemented, probably does the same thing internally, but I think its not very clean as to what is happening.